# NSuserDefault or Sqlite

Tags: iphone

I  just wanna clear some concept about NSuser Default and Sqlite.
plz suggest me, when to use NSUserdefault and when to use sqlite.

can i use NSuserdefault for some  large data??

Answer (score 5):

when you want to store large amount of data with some relationship, go for sqlite if you want to store less value go for NSUserDefault.Sqlite occupies some memory so use it only you really need to save complex datas.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use NSUserDefault when I want to stock user configuration (if you have a config view). It's easy, fast and a really good way to stock some little things about your app.